# Why doesn't my try catch statement work?

Tags: java

The program is fairly simple, I am just a beginner testing out try-catch statements and despite all my reading for 2 days now, I have not been able to understand why this particular try statement will not work for me. I know I could use String instead of int, but I want to know WHY it doesn't work for this, and how I can make it work.
Essentially I want the user to enter 1 or 2, if they enter 1, the program (quiz) will begin, otherwise if they press 2, the program will terminate. If they press anything else, e.g. a letter, another number, or attempt to do literally anything else, it will say something like "try again" and repeat the same loop.

This might seem like a silly question, but i'm very new to this and would be grateful for some clarity.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int score = 0;

System.out.println("Are you ready for a quiz?\n1.yes\n2.no");
int input = scanner.nextInt();

do {
    scanner.nextInt();
        try {

            if (input == 2) {
                System.out.println("Maybe next time!");
                System.exit(0);
            } else if (input == 1) {
                System.out.println("Okay! good luck!\n");
            }

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again\n");
        }
} while (input != 1);
```

Comment: Nothing in your try/catch block throws `InputMismatchException`.

Comment: You need to move the `nextInt` call *into* the `try` block, since it's `nextInt` that potentially throws the exception. (Alternately, use `hasNextInt` to check proactively instead of catching the exception reactively.)

Comment: you don't need try catch, just an additional else block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1***. What is the problem ?

To see `Invalid input. Try again` a `InputMismatchException` have to be thrown inside the `try` block, and it wont happen because the input does not go into the `if` or `else if`, what you expect can be done with

```
try {
   if (input == 2) {
       System.out.println("Maybe next time!");
       System.exit(0);
   } else if (input == 1) {
       System.out.println("Okay! good luck!\n");
   }else{
       throw new InputMismatchException();
   }
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
   System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again\n");
}
```

---

***2***. How to deal with this usage ?

But `Exception` don't have to be used as a normal behaviour, and to be prepare to have `Strings`, you need :

```
System.out.println("Are you ready for a quiz?\n1.yes\n2.no");
String input;
do {
    input= scanner.nextLine();
    if (input.equals("2")) {
       System.out.println("Maybe next time!");
       System.exit(0);
    } else if (input.equals("1")) {
       System.out.println("Okay! good luck!\n");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again\n");
    }     
} while (!input.equals("1"));
```

---

***3***. How to improve it ?

You can change the position of some `print`, so it can be simplified as :

```
System.out.println("Are you ready for a quiz?\n1.yes\n2.no");
String input;
do {
    input= scanner.nextLine();
    if (input.equals("2")) {
       System.out.println("Maybe next time!");
       System.exit(0);
    } 
    System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again\n");             
} while (!input.equals("1"));
System.out.println("Okay! good luck!\n");
```

Comment: This doesn't work. If I enter a letter, it still crashes. It only works if I enter another number (that isn't 1 or 2). Any suggestions?

Comment: @Avan you need to take a String from input, see my edit

Comment: Is there any way to achieve what I want without using string, and sticking to just int? I just want to know from a logic standpoint. Being very stubborn xd

Comment: @Avan you say you want to be able to type letters which are Strings so ... Because using a try/catch as normal process is definitly not a good idea

Comment: Although it is possible to type letters in the console, I don't want it to crash. Instead, I wonder if it can loop again until the user enters an integer? I'm just curious.

Comment: @Avan it's already what it does, until the user type "1" it will loop

Comment: I don't think it's possible to achieve what I want without the String method. I got it to work with string, but this whole int method was an experimentation. If I use NextInt then whenever I input a letter, the program get's stuck in an infinite loop. Can you clarify for a newbie that it is indeed not possible?

Comment: @Avan clarify what ?^^ That you cannot fully with ints if you want to be able to type strings ?^^

Answer (score 1):

I converted int method to String. I thought I could achieve the same thing with just an int method but I could not. Thanks everyone, this is how it works now:

```
enter code hereScanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Are you ready for a quiz?\n1.yes\n2.no");
    String input;

    do {
        input = scanner.nextLine();
        if(input.equals("2")) {
            System.out.println("Maybe next time!");
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (input.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("Okay! good luck!\n");
        }


        else { System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again\n");
        } 

    } while (!input.equals("1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Catch block only executes if there is a  matching exception thrown from the try block.
In this case, there is no exception occurs.

Answer (score -1):

throw the exception in the else block, you missed that.
like follows,

```
     try {
     if (input == 2) {
   System.out.println("Maybe next time!");
    System.exit(0);
    } else if (input == 1) {
     System.out.println("Okay! good luck!\n");
    }else{
     throw new InputMismatchException();
   }
   } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
  System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again\n");
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You are catching specific exception which is InputMismatchException, but your try block has no code which can throw this exception, to handle that scenario, you have to forcefully throw that exception so that your catch block can handle that exception.